# Does multiple azure role instance count means multiple VMs?

Tags: azure-worker-roles

What exactly happens when Azure worker role instance count is set to more than 1? Does this mean multiple VMs? I am using worker role do deploy a socket server. If I set instance count to 2 then will it mean that there will be 2 sockets listening for the requests?

Comment: Did you get the answer you are looking for? Let us know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, basically one role instance is a separate VM.
2 instances also means two open sockets. But access to those sockets would be available via one single Endpoint (declared in role config) and would be automatically load balanced between 2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I heard in the FailSafe series on Channel9 by Mark Simms - web or worker role instance is another VM loaded in the virtualizing host.